# SplitViewController template - Which mechanism is telling the device to perform the segue into the Detail Controller instead of Master Controller

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

In the Apple default Master/Detail template, there is the following code handling the `showDetail` segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

And the storyboard indicating that this segue is type of `Show Detail (e.g. Replace)`

[image]

My question is the following:

> Why in large screen mode (aka: on an iPhone 6+, 7+ or an iPad), the `MasterViewController`'s navigation controller isn't pushing its embedded view as a normal segue would do (which part of the code is making it "working")?

Given the code I'm reading, I would expect on an `iPad` to see the Master Controller to be changed to the Detailed Controller, but the correct behaviour is happening (Master isn't being replaced and Detail is being updated) and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The magic here is the `Show Detail` segue in the storyboard. The code has little to with it. It just passes data to `DetailViewController`. You can even delete the code if you want. The new VC will still be pushed on the detail view.

The "Kind" of the segue here is very special - `Show Detail`:

[image]

This is what causes the new VC to show on the detail view. Try changing the kind to something else like `Show` and the detail view will just be pushed onto the master.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, I did change the `kind` to `Show` as you suggested, it didn't impact the behaviour of the application (from both compact and large screen)